# Make API call to Azure API App in JavaScript with Active Directory authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, azure, active-directory

I implemented an Java API backend which is hosted in Azure as an API app. I switched on authentication by Active Directory. In the CORS settings of the api app I configured allowing calls from the every source just settings an asterisk as URL.

Now I want to get access to the API from a local AngularJS app. My angular code looks like this:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
    .controller('GetDataController', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.login = function(user){
            console.log("user: " + user, user);

            $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
            delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

            $http.get('http://<myapiapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/contacts').
            then(function(response) {
                $scope.greeting = response.data;
                console.log("$scope.greeting: " + $scope.greeting, $scope.greeting);
            });
        }
    });
```

But I still receive the following error within the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.windows.net/
12141bed-36f0-4fc6-b70c-43483f616eb7/oauth2/autho…
%2Fapi%2Fcontacts%23&nonce=ea6b31321cda45d6a4e881fbd0062974_20161026094547.
Redirect from 'https://login.windows.net/12141bed-36f0-4fc6-b70c-43483f616eb7/
oauth2/autho…%2Fapi%2Fcontacts%23&
nonce=ea6b31321cda45d6a4e881fbd0062974_20161026094547' to 
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/12141bed-36f0-4fc6-b70c-43483f616eb7/
oaut…%2Fapi%2Fcontacts%23&nonce=ea6b31321cda45d6a4e881fbd0062974_20161026094547' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So how to get access from AngularJS code?

This is also related to my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40244446/2039740) where I try to get access with a curl call.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are generating HTTP requests directly your Web Apps protected by Azure AD. For this scenario, you can try to implement [ADAL for js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) in your angularJs client. Leveraging adal to gain the authentication token, and when you call your Web Apps in Angular, it will add the authentication header in HTTP requests.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Any way to do this without having to modify the application code?  It appears that when i request the resource, the azure login interceptor isn't respecting CORS, not related to the fact that the request is already authenticated.  I only have Azure AD authentication turned on in my development environment to protect it from unauthorized access.  I want to keep the code base the same between dev and prod.

Comment: No, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#single-page-application-spa for a further understanding of the authorization grand flow against AAD.